# I want to pass String array to textView in another activity in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

This is the first activity

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Songs.this,PlayingSong.class);
Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
bundle.putStringArray("data",songs);
intent.putExtras(bundle);
startActivity(intent);
```

This is the second activity

```
tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.playingSongName);
imge = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.playingImage);

Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

String[] arrRecd = bundle.getStringArray("data");
tv.setText(arrRecd[]);
```

Comment: So what's your question? Is it not working? Is `bundle` null? What is the problem

Answer (score 1):

You can't set a String Array directly to the TextView. Instead create a String and set it to the TextView.

```
String text = "";
for(int i = 0; i < arrRecd.length; i++) {
    text = text + arrRecd[i];
}
tv.setText(text);
```

Answer (score 0):

**In First Activity :**

```
 Intent intent=new Intent(this,SearchActivity.class);
            intent.putStringArrayListExtra("data",songs);
            startActivity(intent);
```

**In second activity:**

```
 ArrayList<String> list=getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("data");
```